# recursive (cascade) selection in python sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a sqlite table with 3 columns named ID (integer), N (integer) and V (real). The pair (ID, N) is unique.

Using the python module sqlite3, I would like to perform a recursive selection with the form

```
select ID from TABLE where N = 0 and V between ? and ? and ID in 
    (select ID from TABLE where N = 7 and V between ? and ? and ID in
        (select ID from TABLE where N = 8 and V between ? and ? and ID in  
            (...)
        )
    )
```

I get the following error, probably because the maximum recursion depth was exceeded (?). I need about 20 to 50 recusion levels

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: parser stack overflow
```

I also tried to join the subselections like

```
select ID from
         (select ID from TABLE where N = 0 and V between ? and ?) 
    join (select ID from TABLE where N = 7 and V between ? and ?) using (ID)
    join (select ID from TABLE where N = 8 and V between ? and ?) using (ID)
    join ...
```

but this approach is supprisingly slow, even with few subselections

Is there a better way to perform the same selection?
Note : the table is indexed on (N, V)

Below is an example to show how the selection works

```
ID  N   V  
0   0   0,1  
0   1   0,2  
0   2   0,3  
1   0   0,5  
1   1   0,6  
1   2   0,7  
2   0   0,8  
2   1   0,9  
2   2   1,2
```

Step 0

```
select ID from TABLE where N = 0 and V between 0 and 0,6
```

ID is in (0,1)
Step 1

```
select ID from TABLE where N = 1 and V between 0 and 1  and ID in (0, 1)
```

ID is still in (0,1)
Step 2

```
select ID from TABLE where N = 2 and V between 0,5 and 1 and ID in (0, 1)
```

ID is 1

Comment: Are the `V` boundaries the same in every step? Where do the `N` values come from? Do you want the IDs from all steps?

Comment: No the V values are different in every step. The N values are arbitrary, just for the example. The idea is simply to refine the selection step by step

Comment: How many steps are there typically? Do you want the IDs from all steps?

Comment: There are generally 20 to 50 steps. Yes I want to get only the IDs that are accepted by all steps

Comment: The selection works fine for 2 or 3 steps

Comment: What's the 'innermost' ID (analogous to the value 0 for factorial, as in factorial(0)=1)?

Answer (score 2):

Unwrap the recursion, do it in reverse order and do it in Python. For this I created a table consisting of 100 records, each with an Id between 0 and 99, N=3 and V=5. Arbitrarily I selected the entire collection of records as the innermost.

You need to imagine having a list of values for N and V indexed so that the values at the head of the list are selected for the last SQL SELECT. What the loop does is simply to take the list of IDs resulting from an inner SELECT to feed it as part of the IN clause to the next SELECT.

Without any indexes this is all over in an augenblick.

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect('recur.db')
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> previous_ids = str(tuple(range(0,100)))
>>> for it in range(50):
...     rows = c.execute('''SELECT ID FROM the_table WHERE N=3 AND V BETWEEN 2 AND 7 AND ID IN %s''' % previous_ids)
...     previous_ids = str(tuple([int(_[0]) for _ in rows.fetchall()]))
...     
>>> previous_ids
'(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99)'
```

Edit: This avoids the use of long strings, takes longer than an augenblick. It's essentially the same idea implemented using tables.

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect('recur.db')
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> N_V = [
... (0, (0,6)),
... (0, (0, 1)),
... (1, (0, 2)),
... (2, (0, 3)),
... (0, (0, 5)),
... (1, (0, 6)),
... (2, (0, 7)),
... (0, (0, 8)),
... (1, (0, 9)),
... (2, (1, 2))
... ]
>>> r = c.execute('''CREATE TABLE essentials AS SELECT ID, N, V FROM the_table WHERE N=0 AND V BETWEEN 0 AND 6''')
>>> for n_v in N_V[1:]:
...     r = c.execute('''CREATE TABLE next AS SELECT * FROM essentials WHERE essentials.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM the_table WHERE N=%s AND V BETWEEN %s AND %s)''' % (n_v[0], n_v[1][0], n_v[1][1]))
...     r = c.execute('''DROP TABLE essentials''')
...     r = c.execute('''ALTER TABLE next RENAME TO essentials''')
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It is a good approach indeed. Do you think this approach can handle large tables? Because (1) I believe that the IN statement has a limited length if you use numeric lists, and (2) this approach impies loading large amount of data (at least for the first iterations), which slows the selection speed.

Comment: I haven't considered a workaround for a limitation in the length of the numeric list; I'm sure you're right about that. What do you mean by 'this approach implies loading [a] large amount of data'?

Comment: I mean that the list "previous_ids" might have a lot of items in the first steps (several millions in my case), then the fetchall command takes time

Comment: I suspect that I've mislead you with that example.

Answer (score 1):

This query requires only the (N, V) index for the subqueries. A separate index on ID might help for the outer query:

```
select ID from t
where ID in (select ID from TABLE where N = 0 and V between ? and ?)
  and ID in (select ID from TABLE where N = 7 and V between ? and ?)
  and ID in (select ID from TABLE where N = 8 and V between ? and ?)
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexing the triplet (ID, N, V) instead of only the (N, V) doublet made the join approach fast enough for being considered

```
create index I on TABLE(ID, N, V)
```

and then

```
select ID from
         (select ID from TABLE where N = 0 and V between ? and ?) 
    join (select ID from TABLE where N = 7 and V between ? and ?) using (ID)
    join (select ID from TABLE where N = 8 and V between ? and ?) using (ID)
    join ...
```